# Snippet count increasing in solr causes Exception in connection with search using asterisk in query

Tags: solr, highlighting

in last days i made my first steps with solr 4.1.0.
So far i had have no problems and could always find a solution, mainly on this great platform.

I am using the example configuration from solr with my own fields.
I am indexing files with tika and add extra fields to the documents.

My Problem is the highlighting:
per default solr returns in highlighting (if enabled) only one hit.
I would like to have them all (-1 doesn't work like in maxAnalyzedChars, so i use 9999 instead) .

I've changed (added) following defaults:

```
<int name="f.text.hl.maxAnalyzedChars">-1</int>
<str name="f.text.hl.snippets">9999</str>
```

in solrconfig.xml at:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">...</requestHandler>
```

Now if i search with placeholders like '*' i.e. "wordtofind*",
the solr server throws following exception:

```
SEVERE: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.StringReader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.StringReader.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizerImpl.zzRefill(StandardTokenizerImpl.java:923)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizerImpl.getNextToken(StandardTokenizerImpl.java:1133)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer.incrementToken(StandardTokenizer.java:180)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.FilteringTokenFilter.incrementToken(FilteringTokenFilter.java:50)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter.incrementToken(LowerCaseFilter.java:54)
        at org.apache.solr.highlight.TokenOrderingFilter.incrementToken(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:633)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.CachingTokenFilter.fillCache(CachingTokenFilter.java:90)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.CachingTokenFilter.incrementToken(CachingTokenFilter.java:55)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter.getBestTextFragments(Highlighter.java:221)
        at org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter.doHighlightingByHighlighter(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:498)
        at org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter.doHighlighting(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:391)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent.process(HighlightComponent.java:139)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:208)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1816)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:448)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:269)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:937)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:998)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:856)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks for any helpfull tip!

ninjax

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am also having this exact same problem with Solr 1.4. I get the exact same IOException if I try to query for a phrase such as "foo bar" (including the quotes). I'm only wanting 2 snippets back unlike your 9999. I have the following params set in my request URL: 

solr/mycore/select?q=%22foo%20bar%22&fl=id,name,description,content&hl=true&hl.fl=description&hl.maxAnalyzedChars=-1&hl.snippets=2

If I change hl.fl to just return the content field instead of the description field then it works fine. I have no idea why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing maxAnalyzedChars from -1 to 2147483647. I stumbled upon this by trying my query using the Java client Solrj. I tried the Integer.MAX_VALUE constant (which is 2^31-1 = 2147483647) and it worked. Adding +1 to that (=2147483648) does not. Hope that helps!